# How to unit test functions that must occur in pairs?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic

Quite often I have some functions that must occur in pairs such as

```
//Example
startSomething()
...
stopSomething()

//Example
openSomething()
...
closeSomething()
```

while unit testing `startSomething()` and `openSomething()` is easy since they require no prior conditions / setup, how should I unit test their counterparts which require the prior to be called?

Answer (score 0):

The majority of unit test frameworks have setup tests which are called before/after all, and/or each, of the test cases. Take NUnit as example:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTest
{
    [OneTimeSetup]
    public void GeneralSetup()
    { ... }  //Called before starts all test cases

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void GeneralTearDown()
    { ... } //Called after all test cases are finished

    [Setup]
    public void Setup()
    { ... }  //Called before each test case

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    { ... } //Called after each test case

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    { ... }

    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    { ... }
}
```